# runtime of checking an array of strings for palindromes

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I wrote a function to find palindromes in an array of strings. at first I looped through the array and checked each item to see if it was a palindrome with a helper function which checks the word (by letter) at each index in the array -- this would be O(n^2) correct?

I then changed my approach to pop off the array (treat it like a stack) and then check if that one item is a palindrome, and do that throughout the array while array.length. This is O(n), correct?

```
'use strict';

function isTextPalindrome(text) {
//this ignores anything other than letters
  text = text.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/g, '').toLowerCase();

  // console.log(text);

  if (!text) {
    return "There must be text as an input!";
  }

  var left = 0;
  var right = text.length - 1;

  while (left < right) {
    if (text[left++] !== text[right--]) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

// console.log(isTextPalindrome('race car'));

function palindromesInArray(arr) {
  var popped;
  var count = 0;
  //treat the array as a stack. don't loop through, just pop off one at a time to avoid extra run time cost.  
  while (popped = arr.pop()) {
    if (typeof (popped) !== 'string') {
      return "Only works on strings";
    }
    if (isTextPalindrome(popped)) {
      count++;
    }
  }

  // for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  //   if (typeof (arr[i]) !== 'string') {
  //     return "Only works on strings";
  //   }
  //   if (isTextPalindrome(arr[i])) {
  //     count++;
  //   }
  // }
 return count;
}



console.log(palindromesInArray(['mom', 'race car', 'dad', 'abba', 'redivider', 'noon', 'civic', 'level', 'blah'])) // returns 8
console.log(palindromesInArray(['mom', 'race car', 'dad', 'blah'])); // returns 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is still unclear what do you mean here by `O(n)` (remember that `O(n)` represents the growth of computation in respect to the length of the input). Here it is not clear with respect do you want to count.

If your `n` is the sum of lengths of all characters in an array of strings, than both of your algorithms is `O(n)`. If you have `n` - the length of your string and `m` the number of your strings in array - you have `O(nm)`.

Answer (score 1):

Checking for a palindrome of a string of length `m` is `O(m)`.

Simply looping over an array (or stack)  of length `n` is `O(n)`.

Doing both is only `O(n^2)` if the maximum string length is `n`. Otherwise, it's `O(n*m)`

Comment: interesting... didn't think of that. is there any way to get a function like this to o(n)?

Comment: Depends what you consider "n". Remember big oh notation is the worst case, which is why I mention the max length string of n.

Comment: hmm. let's say arr is n?

Comment: It'll only be O(n) then if arr is empty :)

Comment: I see...otherwise it will be O(n * m) which is still linear? thanks!

Comment: Worse than linear, actually. It's quadratic if `m = n`, otherwise it's worse than strictly quadratic.